# ASP.NET Core Application Lifecycle

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there any current "ASP.NET Core" document(s) about the life cycle?  I would like to be able to tie into the life cycle at the right points.

Is it similar to the existing ASP.NET MVC 5 life cycle?

http://www-asp.azureedge.net/v-2016-09-01-001/media/4773381/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application.pdf

Comment: It's the same for the most part as there is nothing major (not that I can think of right now) that you should know in addition to your mvc5 knowledge.  Logging for example was move higher into the application creation (main method) so it can log exceptions that cause the system to not load.

Comment: Really, it is not the same at all.

Comment: You can upvote for this on Github in the asp.net docs repo:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/3524

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here are few links I found related to ASP.NET Core lifecycle though this is not complete description and I'm searching for more. ASP.NET Core apps are console apps running on Kestrel so you can assume there are significant differences to what @mybirthname posted and it relates to ASP.NET 5 (and below).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware

http://developer.telerik.com/featured/understanding-asp-net-core-initialization/

I'd suggest going through all the docs within Core docs Fundamentals section.

Comment: this is more like what I was looking for.  I would be overjoyed to see an ASP.NET Core life cycle diagram though.  Your references will be extremely helpful.

Comment: I don't think anything like that is available (yet). But it's basically a set of middleware that runs sequentially.

Comment: You can upvote for a detailed lifecycle overview to be provided on Github in the asp.net docs repo:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/3524

Answer (score 2):

If you have membership of Pluralsight, Alex Wolf has great course on it, He also had same course for previous versions of MVC so if you watch both in order it will give you really good understanding of how Request Life Cycle was working in MVC 5 and before and how it works now with MVC Core and what's difference between both.

Pluralsight also offers 7 days free trial membership if you want to try it out.

**MVC 5 and before:**
[The MVC Request Life Cycle](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/mvc-request-life-cycle)

**MVC Core:**
[ASP.NET Core: The MVC Request Life Cycle](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/aspnet-core-mvc-request-life-cycle)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Probably the best answer for people who have a Pluralsight subscription

Comment: probably the worst answer for the public internet: referencing to restrictive content.

Comment: I saw the course you have mentioned, but it is based on .net core 3. so it is outdated.